# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos \left(x\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$ doesn't exist if $n\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos \left(x\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$ doesn't exist if $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

If $n\in\mathbb{R}$, I could do the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&f(n)=\cos \left(x\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\\\\
&\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
&n_k=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{x}\cdot2\pi k\to\infty\ \ (k\to\infty)\\
&\tilde{n}_k=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{x}\left(\pi(2k+1)+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\to\infty\ \ (k\to\infty)
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
f(n_k)=\cos(2\pi k)=1\to1\ \ (k\to\infty)\\
f(\tilde{n}_k)=\cos\left(\pi(2k+1)+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=-\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\ \ (k\to\infty)
\end{cases}\\\\
&k\in\mathbb{Z} \text{ in all cases}\\
&1\ne-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\Rightarrow\nexists\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)
\end{aligned}
$$
But what to do when $n\in\mathbb{Z}$? Thank you.

Comment: Suppose $x\ne0$

Comment: The limit exists for $x=4k\pi$ where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Write $$u_n = \cos\left(x\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right) \right) \quad \text{ and } v_n = \sin\left(x\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right) \right)\quad $$

and use the relations
$$u_{n+1} = u_n \cos(x) - v_n \sin(x)$$
$$v_{n+1} = v_n \cos(x) + u_n \sin(x) $$

Comment: How could it help? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Suppose that $(u_n)$ converges to a limit $l$ : deduce that $(v_n)$ converges also (to a limit $l'$=, and try to find a contradiction... (noticing that $l^2 + l'^2=1$ can also be useful !)

Comment: But $v_n$ can converge to either $\sqrt{1-l^2}$ or $-\sqrt{1-l^2}$, because $u_n^2+v_n^2=1$. So, why does $\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n$ exist?

Comment: Because of the first relation I wrote, you must have $l=l \cos(x) - l' \sin(x)$. You can deduce the value of $l'$.

Comment: So if $\sin x\ne0$ or $x=\pi+2\pi m,\ m\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have a contradiction, and if $x=2\pi m$, everything seems to be fine?

Comment: In the latter case, the limit should be -1, indeed. So, I think I got your solution, thank you!